# Elastic Search aggregation find if a field exist in all records

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index on Elastic Search, most records have field `foo`, some may not.

I want to know if all records have field `foo` by doing an aggregation.

case 1:

```
id = 0, foo = 1, bar = 1
```

doing such aggregation would give me `fooContainsNull = false`, because all records contains `foo`

case2:

```
id = 0, foo = 1, bar = 1
id = 1, bar = 1
```

doing such aggregation would give me `fooContainsNull = true`, because one of the record (id = 1) doesn't have `foo`

I tried using filter aggregation

```
    "aggregations": {
        "fooContainsNull": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "not": {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "foo"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

but `bool` and `not` cant seem be used together.

How can I achieve this using Elastic Search aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `not` by `must_not`,

```
"aggregations": {
        "fooContainsNull": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "foo"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

This will give you number of docs that doesn't have field `foo` against `fooContainsNull`. Accordingly you can build logic by checking this number is 0 or greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

or even better

```
aggs: {
  aggregationName: {
    missing: {
      field: 'fieldName'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is that even better?

Comment: @JeremyCaney because it is cleaner